# Product of $2$ integers roots is an integer root proof

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to prove that if a number is an integer root as in $n$ is the number then $n^k$ = $m$ where $k$ is a natural number and $m$ is an integer. So if I have $a$ and $b$ that are integer roots then $ab$ is an integer root too. I was thinking proof by contradiction and say that if they're integer roots their product is a fraction, but it didn't work out.

Comment: If $a^p=m$ and $b^q=n$ then $(ab)^{pq}=a^{pq}b^{pq}=m^qn^p$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and make the question more clear.

Comment: $a,b$ are integer roots with the same $k$ I take it? Otherwise you end up with say 8 and 9, but 72 isn't an integer root.